# Django forms target foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form for submitting an order. Multiple items have been attached to a catalog object, I'd like to have the form dropdown contain options for all of the items attached to the foreign key, instead of the foreign key Catalog name of Available. I know how to access these in the view, using the related name, is this possible in forms?

Here is my current form:

```
from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, ButtonHolder, Submit

from . import models

class OrderListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('order_lines',)
        model = models.Order

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'order_lines',
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('create', 'Create')

            )


        )
```

Here is my model:

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.products

class Issue(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, related_name='issue_products')
    Volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.catalog)


class Annual(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, related_name='annual_products')
    year_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    end_date = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.year_id)


class Annual_Issue(models.Model):
    annual_id = models.ForeignKey(Annual, related_name='annual_ids')
    issue_id = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='issues')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.annual_id


class Article(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, related_name='article_products')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    abstract = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    full_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    proquest_link = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    ebsco_link = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='who_ordered')
    order_lines = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='items_ordered')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access all the Annuals and Articles that are in the same catalog by using:

```
c = Catalog.objects.get(....
c.article_products_set.all()
c.annual_products_set.all()
```

Comment: Would I add this logic to the Class in forms.py?

Comment: "I know how to access these in the view, using the related name, is this possible in forms?" so if I understand correctly - he want to set crispy-forms Layout for all fields of the related model in one OrderListForm

Comment: but it is wrong approach, you should use forms and formsets instead

Comment: yes, currently my form is returning the Catalog products charfield as the option. I would like it to return the related fields that are attached to it. (issues, articles, annuals)